# using system() in C++;does not work

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I need to execute this command in my c++ code:
**mkdir -p sample_directory/{1..10}**
to make 10 directory . But when I use it in system function in my code:

```
system("mkdir -p sample_director/{1..10}");
```

after execution this make just one directory by this name :**{1..10}**
how can i fix it?

Comment: I haven't created directories using {1..10}. Try {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} ? Does this work?

Comment: it doesn't work, my directory name is :{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion is not in POSIX, so not all shells implement it. In particular, in POSIX, `system` is supposed to invoke `sh`, which is supposed to act like a "plain" POSIX shell rather than `bash` or some other feature-rich shell. So it won't do the brace expansion.

You could directly invoke `bash` if you want `bash` to process the command...

```
system("bash -c 'mkdir -p sample_director/{1..10}'");
```

or you could just make 10 separate `system` calls. Or other workarounds, I'm sure you can think of some.

Comment: Or better, 10 separate `mkdir` calls.

Comment: @ninjalj You can't pass a `-p` option to the `mkdir` function.

Comment: @Brian: you can create the parent directories with additional `mkdir()` calls, which is better than spawning a full-blown shell just to create some directories. Spawning a shell is slow, may require more swap space to avoid failing with ENOMEM, and introduces subtle dependencies on the environment (cf. shellshock)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try to do the same using a loop construct.

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        string str="mkdir -p sample_director/" + to_string(i);  
        system(str.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And run your code with `c++11` support

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 my_program.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `dash` doesn't support brace expansion (syntax like `{1..10}`). The `system` function doesn't care about the value of your `SHELL`, it always passes provided arguments to `/bin/sh`. And on Ubuntu `/bin/sh` refers to `dash`, which cannot handle brace expansion. On some other distributions (like Arch), `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `bash`, so your code will work fine.

If I were you, I wouldn't use `system` at all in this case. `Boost::filesystem` (or even `mkdir`/`mkdirat`) seems like a better option to me.